# ORA-00972 Identifier is too long: while creating tablespace

Tags: oracle, tablespace

This is a practice assignment where I have to create a table space with two datafiles. We have to use the exact naming conventions that are given to us. I believe I have it right, but I get this error: "**ORA-00972: identifier is too long**". I think I'm getting this because the path and filename are so long. The question is, how do I get around this?

Thanks!

```
CREATE TABLESPACE CTTT444_tbs
DATAFILE "C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\oradata\cttt444_1.dbf" SIZE 15M,
DATAFILE "C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\oradata\cttt444_2.dbf" SIZE 15M,
AUTOEXTEND ON
NEXT 5m
MAXSIZE 100m);
```

Comment: http://www.dba-oracle.com/sf_ora_00972_identifier_is_too_long.htm

Comment: Thanks. I actually read over that before. How can I specify the path and filename thought without exceeding 30 characters? Is that the problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[File specification](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/clauses004.htm#i998826) should be single quotes. Try:

```
CREATE TABLESPACE CTTT444_tbs
DATAFILE 'C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\oradata\cttt444_1.dbf' SIZE 15M,
DATAFILE 'C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\oradata\cttt444_2.dbf' SIZE 15M
AUTOEXTEND ON
NEXT 5m
MAXSIZE 100m;
```

It also looks like you have some syntax errors in the command (such as the right parenthesis).

Answer (score 1):

FYI for those with the same issue. This seemed to work for me.

```
CREATE TABLESPACE CTTT444_tbs
DATAFILE 'C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\oradata\cttt444_1.dbf' SIZE 15M,
 'C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\oradata\cttt444_2.dbf' SIZE 15M
AUTOEXTEND ON
NEXT 5m
MAXSIZE 100m;
```

OR

```
CREATE TABLESPACE CTTT444_tbs
DATAFILE 'C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\oradata\cttt444.dbf' SIZE 15M
AUTOEXTEND ON
NEXT 5m
MAXSIZE 100m;

ALTER TABLESPACE CMIS420_tbs ADD DATAFILE 'C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\oradata\cttt444.dbf' SIZE 15M;
```